# C# Set encoding to read and write File with special characters

Tags: c#, file, encoding, stream, french

I have a csv file with special characters from French and German language, for example:
é, ü, ö...
this file needs to be rearranged in program into different csv format.
Problem is special characters in result file are replaced either by � or just ?
I checked and reading source file is not good:

```
Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
string fileName = @"D:\temp\sourceFile.csv";
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName, encoding);
```

when I checked what is in lines list, already there special letters are replaced with ?, so the reading of file is not good in the first place. I tried various encoding but none of them works. Original csv file is ANSI, I don't know why that doesn't work at all.

in the end result is written into result file:

```
 TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(@"d:\temp\Result.csv", false, encoding);
 foreach (var item in result)
    {
            tw.WriteLine(item.Key + ";" + item.Value);
    }

 tw.Close();
```

This encoding seems to be a problem from the start. I tried various including Encoding.Default, nothing works. Please, help!

Comment: You could try with `Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")` for the very common western european encoding.

Answer (score 0):

i have same problem:

you could try some encodings if Default not functional:

```
        "Windows 1252" -> Encoding.GetEncoding(1252); #Europe Ouest (Windows)
        "ISO-8859-1" -> Encoding.GetEncoding(28591); #Europe occidentale (ISO)
```